# always getting null response from Room Query

Tags: android-room

Every time I try to fetch the record getting null exception but I am able to insert the records properly.Please help me out I am really struck

---

code snippet for fetching the  record from room database

```
  @Override
    public  LoginSessionEntity getLoginSessionRecord(final String sessionId) {
        final LoginSessionEntity[] status = new LoginSessionEntity[1];
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                status[0] = iglDAO.getLoginSessionRecord(sessionId);
            }
        });

        return status[0];
    }
```

// DAO

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT  * FROM  login_session where sessionId =:sessionid")
    LoginSessionEntity  getLoginSessionRecord(String sessionid );
```

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = AppConstants.TableNames.TABLE_LOGIN_SESSION)
public class LoginSessionEntity {



@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
@SerializedName("SessionId")
@Expose
private Integer sessionId;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_FIRST_USER_REG_NO)
@SerializedName("RegistrationNo")
@Expose
private String registrationNoOne;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_SECOND_USER_REG_NO)
private String registrationNoTwo;
@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_FIRST_USER_NAME)
private String nameOne;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_SECOND_USER_NAME)
private String nametwo;
@SerializedName("Rank")
@Expose
private String rank;
@SerializedName("URL")
@Expose
private String uRL;
@SerializedName("LoginTime")
@Expose
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_FIRST_LOGIN_TIME)
private String loginTimeOne;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_SECOND_LOGIN_TIME)
private String loginTimeTwo;
@SerializedName("UserTypeId")
@Expose
private int userTypeId;
@SerializedName("BaseURL")
@Expose
private String baseURL;
@SerializedName("UnitCode")
@Expose
private String unitCode;
private String imei;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_FIRST_LOGIN_STATUS)
private boolean loginStatusOne;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_SECOND_LOGIN_STATUS)
private boolean loginStatusTwo;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_FIRST_LOGOUT_TIME)
private String logoutTimeOne;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_SECOND_LOGOUT_TIME)
private String logoutTimeTwo;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_FIRST_LOGIN_TYPE_ID)
private int loginTypeIdOne;
@ColumnInfo(name = AppConstants.ColumnNames.COLUMN_SECOND_LOGIN_TYPE_ID)
private int loginTypeIdTwo;
private int routeId;
private String sourceId;
@Ignore
private String message;
```

Exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.igl.igllpm_new, PID: 19089
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.igl.igllpm_new.database.tables.LoginSessionEntity.getUserTypeId()' on a null object reference
    at com.igl.igllpm_new.component.splash.SplashActivity.onLoginSessionEntity(SplashActivity.java:183)
    at com.igl.igllpm_new.component.splash.SplashPresenter.getLoginrecord(SplashPresenter.java:66)
    at com.igl.igllpm_new.component.splash.SplashActivity.NavigateToMainScreen(SplashActivity.java:107)
    at com.igl.igllpm_new.component.splash.SplashActivity$2.onClick(SplashActivity.java:165)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:176)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1565)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1453)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the implemented  `getLoginSessionRecord(final String sessionId)` method, the method returns created array on current thread. Executor runs the inline runnable in separate thread so value is set after return. Instead,you can allow main thread queries and directly use interface method. Call `allowMainThreadQueries()` on room database builder but this may slow down UI thread. Another solution would be using LiveData for asynchronous reach DB. Check out [room accessing data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data) document for more info.